# Convert unsigned char* array to std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, stringstream, stdstring

I'm using this code to convert the unsigned char* (points to an array of 256 values) to std::string:

```
int ClassA::Func(unsigned char *dataToSend, int sendLength)
{
    std::stringstream convertStream;
    std::string dataToSendStr = "";

    for(int i=0; i<=sendLength; i++) convertStream << dataToSend[i];    

    while(!convertStream.eof()) convertStream >> dataToSendStr;
    ...
}
```

but then I have dataToSendStr in this format:

```
dataToSendStr "" 
[0]           0x00 
[1]           0x00 
[2]           0x04 
[3]           0xC0
```

if I now use this value I only get "" and not the important values [0-3]!

-> need something like: dataToSendStr "000004C0"

Thx for your help!

Comment: As an aside, you don't have to use the `for() ...` construct to write the elements to a stream.  You can use `copy( dataToSend, dataToSend+sendLength, ostream_iterator<string>(convertStream) );` if you want to avoid hand-written loops.

Comment: When you say "need something like", did you actually mean "this is the exact string I want given this input"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the IO manipulator [std::hex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) if you want (which is what I *think* based on the *need something like* part of the question) a hexadecimal representation of the characters in `dataToSend`:

```
std::ostringstream convertStream;
convertStream << std::hex << std::setfill('0');

for (int i = 0; i < sendLength; i++)
{
    convertStream << std::setw(2) << static_cast<short>(dataToSend[i]);
}
```